# MEAN.io MyPackage.aggregateAsset global: false still applies to entire site

Tags: mean.io

When I set global: false in the app.js for a package, the css is still applied to the entire app instead of just that package. You can test with with mean upload package. For example set the h1 background to purple in the public/assets/css/meanUpload.css and then set global: false in the app.js

```
Upload.aggregateAsset('css', '../css/meanUpload.css', {
    global: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are misunderstanding the purpose of the global attribute. **Global** is only to say if the code that you want to add is going to be wrapped by a closure or not.

You can check that here : http://learn.mean.io/#mean-stack-packages-assets-and-aggregation